# How to Call A simple Bool function and print

Tags: c, function, boolean

I am trying to learn how to call functions and work with bools. Tried running a small test by calling a bool function that is true if an input number is less than 50. However I am getting an error saying that the function is missing an argument list whatever that is. Any advice as to what im doing wrong is much appreciated. thankyou!

C4550: Expression evaluates to a function which is missing an argument list.

error is pointing to where i am calling the bool function in main.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ValidInput(int number1);
int number1;

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number1);

    if (ValidInput == true)
        printf("VALID INPUT\n");
}

bool ValidInput(int number1)
{
    if (number1 < 50)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you read any C code, written by anyone else, ever?

Comment: Please post the exact compiler error. Also, there's a curly brace missing somewhere.

Comment: You call functions with `()`.

Comment: Read the error message _C4550: Expression evaluates to a function which is missing an argument list._ Change `if (ValidInput == true)` to `if (ValidInput(number1) == true)`. Your `ValidInput` function has one argument, you have to pass it.

Answer (score 1):

In this if statement

```
if (ValidInput == true)
{
    printf("VALID INPUT");
}
```

you are comparing function pointer `ValidInput` with true.

But your intention is to compare the result of the function call with true. So write

```
if (ValidInput( number1 ) == true)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    printf("VALID INPUT");
}
```

And it would be more safe just to write

```
if ( ValidInput( number1 ) )
```

instead of

```
if (ValidInput( number1 ) == true)
```

Also the function itself can be written simpler

```
bool ValidInput(int number1)
{
    return number1 < 50;
}
```

Take into account that there is no need to declare variable `number1` like a global variable. And function main should be declared with the parameter list void. You should write

```
int main( void )
{
    int number1;
    //...
```

Comment: ooooooh, i am so sorry for asking such a simple question. i am an idiot. thankyou so much.

Comment: There are no idiot questions, but the one that is not formulated by fear.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool ValidInput;
int number1;

int main()
{
printf("Enter number:");
scanf_s("%d", &number1);

if (ValidInput(number1) == true)
{
    printf("VALID INPUT");
}
}

bool ValidInput(int number1)
{
    if (number1 < 50)
    {
    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed adding braces after if()... Functions cannot be nested in C.